# Internal Server Error while processing the php curl code

Tags: php, curl

I have a 'curl' code in php as

```
  $ch = curl_init("http://www.abcd.in/upload.php");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("file" => "@$file", "file_name" => "$file_name"));

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

   curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);
```

the upload.php is as

```
 $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $file_name = $_POST["file_name"];
$file_extension = substr(strrchr($file_name, '.') , 1);

$path = "uploads/".date("YmdHis", time()).uniqid().".$file_extension";
move_uploaded_file($file, $path);
```

after executing this code although the image is getting uploaded,I am getting a Internal Server Error-500.
How can I overcome this?

Comment: "file_name" => "$file_name"... oh my... why not just "file_name" => $file_name ?

Comment: and second. where 500 error occures? on server to which you upload the image or on sever where this curl code runs?

Comment: on the sever where this curl code runs

Comment: @Varada if your code executes and the file appears on the remote server, this means the 500 is coming from somewhere else in your script, after the curl functions are executed. Can you post a full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to see the apache log error and just verify as you installed

```
sudo apt-get install curl php5-curl php5-xmlrpc
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This one can't work to upload anything, you forgot `CURLOPT_POST`.
2. IF you're getting 500, it can't be uploaded
3. It's target server problem when it's returning 500. Check configuration

Comment: thank you for your help. But I am able to upload the file with the code in upload.php.. I can see it in the server, but still am getting this error